# Installation issues github program: truecrack

Tags: command-line, terminal, git, truecrypt, osx-el-capitan

I am trying to install TrueCrack from github: https://github.com/lvaccaro/truecrack . As the description says I do this:

```
cd truecrackDirectory
./configure --enable-cpu
make
```

However, when I do the `make`, the command ends with this error:

```
[...]
Common/CpuCore.c:99:3: error: non-void function 'cpu_Core_charset' should return
  a value [-Wreturn-type]
            return;
            ^
[...]
44 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CpuCore.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 68 cpu_Core_charset is declared to return an int (integer). It appears from line 106 the intended error value is 0. Modify line 99 by adding the return value 0:

```
    else{
        perror("Key derivation function not supported");
        return 0;
    }
```

The make will complete, albeit with more warnings.